# How to permanently append a path to Python for Linux?

Tags: python

I know there are multiple solutions online, but some are for windows, some are environmental variable, etc..

What is the best way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find your site-packages directory and create a new file called `myproj.pth`

Inside that file, put each directory you want to add, one per line like so:

```
/home/myuser/svn-repos/myproject
/home/myuser/svn-repos/SomeOtherProject
```

Python loads `*.pth` every time it runs, and imports all paths in each of those files.

In Ubuntu, that directory can often be found at
`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/`

Comment: What if you install python3.1? then the path(es) won't be imported

Comment: That is by design. Python 3k is substantially different than python 2.x, and so you need to re-do this sort of configuration. If you're already using Py3k, put your .pth in the Py3k site-packages directory.

Comment: Well, what if you were on 2.5 and then you moved to 2.6? My point is, you'll have to copy this file around, where as if you define PYTHONPATH in `~/.bashrc` you won't have such an issue

Comment: If you define PYTHONPATH in your ~/.bashrc, you have to copy that file around for each user of your system. Ever have anyone else do work on the same machine? Ever do work as www-admin?

Comment: Then put it in /usr/local/lib/site-python. That'll stay constant from install to install. I recommended the specific version site path because it keeps python from barfing when you change versions and your code is incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

I personally just define `PYTHONPATH` in `~/.bashrc`, as for what's the "best" approach? I think that's hard to answer (or rather, there's no correct answer). It *depends*.

Comment: You might want to take out the waffling and just say `PYTHONPATH` so we can vote that up.

Comment: Well, the "waffling" is part of my answer. I mean, obviously the dude already knows about `PYTHONPATH`, so just mentioning it alone doesn't add any value.

Comment: Adding in .bashrc does not work for ipython qtconsole when it is not run from a terminal. The other answer works though.